# Why does requests.post raise 404 Not found code?

Tags: python

does anyone have any idea, why the output of this script, where i use requests.post to login is code 404, Not found, and the same script, where I use only requests.get has code 200 OK? What should I change?

```
import requests
URL = 'https://www.stratfor.com/login'
session = requests.Session()
page = session.post(URL)
print(page.status_code, page.reason)
```

Thank you.

Comment: When trying to login on their webpage by using the login form, the request is posted to https://www.stratfor.com/api/v3/user/login, not the URL you tried. Also, you are not supplying any values for `password` and `username`, and they possibly want proper cookies set too. If you're one of their customers, your time is probably better spent by contacting their support than writing on a public forum.

Comment: @chelmertz it not seems that he tryng to log in the login page is not where you sould send the password and the username

Answer (score 1):

it seem to be  worked with get request and should returned 405 but it depends on the server

Answer (score 0):

One good way to note the right page to log in is to log the network calls.

After looking at the calls, a request is sent to

`URL = https://www.stratfor.com/api/v3/user/login`

The API endpoint actually expects a payload like this:

`payload = {username: "YOU_USER", password: "YOUR_PASS"}`

Try something like this:

`r = requests.post(URL,json=payload)`

You might need to pass more headers, which you can poke the network call log for. Although, it seems like that user and password are passed as raw strings here? If so, that's definitely not safe.

Comment: Thank you, how can I find the right name for username and password for usage in payload? On the login page which I posted I can find it by right-click and inspect the code of the page, but the requested endpoint has nothing like that.
I am sorry for the question. Everytime I tried to login through requests.post the request URL was the same as login page, so I have not any experience with that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The username and password you should pass is the combination that will aloow you to authenticate with the website / service. Are you able to log in manually? Maybe try the same user/pass combo in the payload then.

Comment: @hejmatt you may check the request paramter in the server side or in the html code.